# I'm trying to make a basic NFT contract, But I keep getting a error "DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier."

Tags: solidity

Smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-LICENSE-IDENTIFIER: UNLICENSE
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract SimpleMintContract is ERC721, Ownable {
   uint256 public mintPrice = 0.00 ether;
   uint256 public totalSupply;
   uint256 public maxSupply;
   bool public isMintEnabled;
   mapping(address => uint256) public mintedWallets;

   constructor() payable ERC721('Simple Mint', 'SIMT') {
       maxSupply = 2;
   }
       

function toggleIsMintEnabled() external onlyOwner {
     isMintEnabled = !isMintEnabled;
    }

    function setMaxSupply(uint256 maxSupply_) external onlyOwner {
        maxSupply = maxSupply_;
    }

    function mint() external payable {
        require(isMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
        require(mintedWallets[msg.sender] < 1, 'exceeds max per wallet' ) ;
        require(msg.value == mintPrice, 'wrong value');
        require(maxSupply > totalSupply, 'sold out');

        mintedWallets[msg.sender]++;
        totalSupply++;
        uint256 totalId = totalSupply;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId); 
^ this is the line with the issue in remix

Answer (score 0):

You must to declare your tokenId. This variable meaning the identifier of your NFT. In your smart contract  you don't declare a variable called tokenId with relative value. In your case you have two options:

- resolve this problem declaring a variable called tokenId and setting  ID of  NFT like this:

  ```
  function mint() external payable {
          require(isMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
          require(mintedWallets[msg.sender] < 1, 'exceeds max per wallet' ) ;
          require(msg.value == mintPrice, 'wrong value');
          require(maxSupply > totalSupply, 'sold out');

          mintedWallets[msg.sender]++;
          totalSupply++;
          uint256 totalId = totalSupply;
          // NOTE: I specificy the tokenId of my first NFT
          // First NFT has identifier: 0
          uint tokenId = 0;
          _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
      }
  ```
- change your variable from tokenId to totalId. In this case when you generate multiple NFTs, these will'get the identifier of the variable totalSupply. Example: When you deploy the smart contract totalSupply is 0. When I call, for the first time, mint() function, totalSupply variable is incrementing with this instruction totalSupply++; and the identifier of token is 1. At second time when a user interact with mint() function, the identifier of second NFT is 2 (incrementing totalSupply + 1) and so on.
  This is code in this case:

  ```
  function mint() external payable {
     require(isMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
     require(mintedWallets[msg.sender] < 1, 'exceeds max per wallet' );
     require(msg.value == mintPrice, 'wrong value');
     require(maxSupply > totalSupply, 'sold out');
     mintedWallets[msg.sender]++;
     totalSupply++;
     uint256 totalId = totalSupply;
     _safeMint(msg.sender, totalId);
  }
  ```

I think that in your case you must to follow the second option that I explained.